# Find value of $\tan 1 \times \tan 2 \times ........\times \tan 89.$

Tags: trigonometry

Find value of $\tan 1 \times \tan 2 \times \cdots \times \tan 89.$ Please don't answer, but please help me to figure this out this as I am not aware of any method to calculate this. I tried it by finding value of $\tan(90^\circ)$, but it didn't work as $\tan(90^\circ)$ is not-defined.

Comment: Start with evaluating $\tan 1^\circ \tan 89^\circ$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $\tan(x)\times\tan(90^\circ-x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\times\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \tan 89^\circ = \cot(90^\circ-89^\circ) = \cot 1^\circ = \frac 1 {\tan 1^\circ}, \\[10pt]
\text{so } & \tan 1^\circ \times\tan89^\circ = 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Upvoting in order to cancel those stupid delete votes. In any case, this is sufficiently close to the other answer, so if it were mine, I would probably delete it myself.

Comment: @AlexM. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/a-minor-gripe-about-upvoting-things-that-have-been-downvoted

Comment: @ZacharySelk: I do agree with that, and I have "voted to compensate" less than 15 times in 5 years (subjective estimate). I don't do it in order to compensate for downvotes, but to annihilate pending delete votes that would lead to the loss of a valid answer. If you have a better solution I shall gladly adopt it.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\tan(90-A)=\cot A$ and $\tan A\times\cot A=1$

Here we have $\tan1\cdot\tan2\cdot\tan3\cdots\tan45\cdot\cot44\cdot\cot43\cdots\cot1$.

$(\tan89=\cot1,\tan46=\cot44)$

And we get $\tan45$ as our answer.